# With Pandas, how do I split out row values into separate columns, and use their value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if the title is unclear, I'll clarify with an example shortly.

I have a dataframe in Pandas where the first column is a specific value, say, a country, and there are other rows depicting relationships between that country and other countries, and each of those rows has a numeric value indicating on a scale of 0 to 1 (floating point) on how good terms the two countries are.

Here's an example:

```
COUNTRY1         COUNTRY2         RELATIONSHIP
Germany          Australia        0.8
Germany          Turkey           0.9
Germany          Mexico           0.5
Germany          Australia        0.75
Hungary          Australia        0.4
Hungary          Mongolia         1.0
Australia        Turkey           0.3
Australia        Mexico           0.8
...
```

I want to consolidate it into:

```
COUNTRY         GERMANY         AUSTRALIA         TURKEY         MEXICO ...
Germany            -               0.8              0.9            0.5
Australia         0.75              -               0.3            0.8  
...
```

Is such a thing possible? Essentially splitting rows into unique columns, and keeping a value?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`pd.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table):

```
>>> agg = lambda ts: ts.iloc[0] if 1 == len(ts) else tuple(ts)
>>> df.pivot_table(values='RELATIONSHIP',
...                index='COUNTRY1',
...                columns='COUNTRY2',
...                aggfunc=agg).fillna('-')
COUNTRY2     Australia Mexico Mongolia Turkey
COUNTRY1                                     
Australia            -    0.8        -    0.3
Germany    (0.8, 0.75)    0.5        -    0.9
Hungary            0.4      -        1      -
```

Answer (score -1):

pd.pivot should fit right in.

```
pd.pivot(index="COUNTRY1", columns="COUNTRY2", values="RELATIONSHIP")
```

Comment: This throws a `ValueError`